# How can I create foam and spray in a fluid simulation?

Tags: fluid-simulation

Hi! I'm working on simulating an ocean; after working on it for quite a while, I've come to the realization that my ocean is missing the characteristic ocean foam and spray.

I saw some vids where there is a fluid that interacts with objects and foam and spray appears; how was this accomplished? (I tried to use dynamic paint but it didn't work, at least not the way I did it.)

Any help appreciated!

Thanks,

EvilAsuratos

Comment: i ment Fluid simulation Not